# event handling in multiple checkedlistbox

Tags: vb.net, checkedlistbox

i am new in vb.net and im thinking if there is a possible way to handle all checkedlistbox events inside a tabcontrol

here is my code for one checkedlistbox and i guess that it is inefficient to paste this to the rest of the 49 checkedlistboxes

```
  Private Sub cbA1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As     System.EventArgs) Handles cbA1.SelectedIndexChanged

    For i = 0 To cbA1.Items.Count - 1
        cbA1.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Unchecked)
    Next
    cbA1.SetItemCheckState(cbA1.SelectedIndex, CheckState.Checked)
'DISABLE CHKBOX AFTER PICKING THE CHOICE
    cbA1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Comment: are you using checkbox or checkboxlist

Comment: checkboxlist, they are also filled with list of items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I usually do to handle many objects with just 1 event.

```
Private Sub cb_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbA1.SelectedIndexChanged, cbA2.SelectedIndexChanged, cbA3.SelectedIndexChanged 'and add more checkedlistbox here separated by comma
   For i = 0 To sender.Items.Count - 1
      sender.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Unchecked)
   Next

   sender.SetItemCheckState(sender.SelectedIndex, CheckState.Checked)

   'DISABLE CHKBOX AFTER PICKING THE CHOICE
   sender.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

how to get the checked values in checkedlistbox, can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

this code will get the index

```
For Each indexChecked In CheckedListBox1.CheckedIndices
   MessageBox.Show("Index " + itemChecked.ToString() + " is checked.")
Next
```

this code will get the value

```
For Each itemChecked In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
   MessageBox.Show(itemChecked.ToString() & " is checked")
Next
```

change 'CheckedListBox1' to 'sender' and put it inside Sub cb_SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: thanks for the help also i would like to know which of the checkboxlist is selected. like sending a text that's cba3 is selected

Comment: @AJNovice : I have added it in my answer. Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub CheckedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        For i = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            If CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndex = i Then
                CheckedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```